# boostrap textbox only shows one line

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

i dont know why, but my textbox only displays the text in one line. So the textbox is only one thin line, where the text is displayed. I put the row number to 5, but it still doesnt change anything. I want to show my text in a properly sized Textbox.

[image: how it looks now]

```
<div class='textbox'>
    <div class='offset-md-0'>
        <label for='comment'>Persoenlicher Kommentar:</label>
        <pre class = 'form-control' id='comment' rows='5'>$p_text</pre>
        <div id='charNum'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: problem is `pre` tag, change another tag like `p`. etc

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to p and now the text is showing but the textbox is still the same size. Look at my edited picture.

Comment: change <pre> with <textarea> and then set rows attribute to show number of rows by default

Comment: you could use `textarea` which would work. Made a working snippet for the same. Have a look at it

Comment: Using text area is a poor solution. Think about what the problem is and find out what might be causing it. In your case, is the fixed height in the `form-control` class. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form-control` class has a fixed height. This is causing your problem. To solve it, change the pre tag for another one and add the `h-auto` class.

Using the `textarea` tag with a specific height is temporary and poor solution. If your text changes and occupies more or less, you will have to change the height to match. The moment you have several of these blocks each with its heights, you will have a good mess.

You can also dispense with this class and use other bootstrap utilities to achieve a similar result.

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/aqu20gxw/

Answer (score 0):

`rows` attribute only works with the `textarea` element:

```html
<textarea class="form-control" id="comment" rows="5">$p_text</textarea>
```

If you don't want the user to edit the content, either use the `readonly` attribute, or wrap your text into another element with a custom CSS rule `height`.

```html
<p class="form-control" id="comment">$p_text</p>

<style>
  #comment {
    height: 10rem;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the better output with bootstrap `textarea` tag. You can check it by referring [Get started with bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/)

Comment: Yes, use rows="5" under the <textarea> command give you the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textarea` instead

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="4"  placeholder="Message" readonly > hello</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<texarea>` tag instead of `<pre>`

```html
<textarea class="form-control" id="comment" rows="5">your data($p_text)</textarea>
```